# How to pass custom headers to cURL?

Tags: php, curl, header

Sorry for my English. Tell me how to pass non-standard headers in cURL

```
$headers = array("Accept: application/json, text/plain, /*", 
        "Captcha: NDRMR9",
        "Referer: https://avtokod.mos.ru/AutoHistory/");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://avtokod.mos.ru/AutoHistory/GetByLicensePlate");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('licensePlate' => $licensePlate, 'sts' => $sts)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cookie.txt");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $response;
    print_r($info['request_header']);
```

But I get an error

> {"code":1,"message":"Необходимо ввести капчу"}

I. e. I didn't send a captcha.

I can see that in the debugger the Captcha parameter is passed in the header

[open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KccT.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to your image, you're already sending the header. Maybe look at the documentation of the service you're calling to see how does it expect the captcha.

Comment: Also, don't post errors or code as images, copy it as text.

Comment: @Alejandro I may have incorrectly explained. The image shows the request I made from the browser.